# magento 2 move inactive quote to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, quote

I want to move an inactive quote to the checkout page.

A customer searches for products and adds them in the cart but doesn't want to checkout on that day.

Now on next day he wants to order some products which are not present in the current cart. He also wants to keep all the current product in the cart.

My solution to this is, the customer will make the current cart(quote) to inactive (By clicking some button on the cart page). This quote will be visible in my account section.

I need an ability to move this inactive cart to an active cart. That is when the customer wants to continue to do checkout of this quote.

Comment: Explain in some more detail, what you are looking for?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have edited the question please look into this. 
Thank you

Comment: please check this one  : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-email-quote-pro.html

Comment: I don't want to buy the plugin. I want to build it.

Comment: move cart to wishlist

Comment: No not a wish list. In wish list i have to again add those products from wishlist to cart. What i want is to add all product which were added a day before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the

`$activeQuoteId` is the id of current activeQuote

`$inActiveQuoteId` is the id of current inactiveQuote

And 2 quotes must belong to customer,

You should active which quote do you want for customer, then set to current checkout session.

```
        /** @var $activeQuote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $activeQuote = $this->quoteRepository->get($activeQuoteId);
        $activeQuote->setIsActive(0);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($activeQuote);

        /** @var $inActiveQuote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $inActiveQuote = $this->quoteRepository->get($inActiveQuoteId);
        $inActiveQuote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($inActiveQuote);

        /** @var $session \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session */
        $session->replaceQuote($inActiveQuote);
```